# Linux server with cups daemon connected to active directory protecting clients from using drivers or PPDs

Tags: printing, cups, postscript

I want to create a printer server (Ubuntu 16.04) running a cups daemon and sharing its connected printers with multiple clients (even Ubuntu 16.04).

Right now those clients can use the printers but I have to provide a lot of PPDs to all of them. I only want to provide the new print server and its cups with the necessary PPDs.

I read some articles about this topic and it is said, that there is no "API" like Windows GDI. Nevermind - the only clients will be Linux hosts.

Is there a way to realize such a setup? The goal is to connect the clients to the print servers cups daemon without installing any kind of PPDs on the clients.

I tried IPP and to add a printer like ipp://printserver.loremipsum.de/printer/BrotherXYZ123 on the client but it was asked for PPDs.